# Cant figure out how to fix this. Python Selenium Chromedriver Error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

Game_Pin = input('Enter your PIN: ')
NickNAME = input('Enter your nickname: ')

def Enter_Press():
    browser.find_element_by_name("Enter").click()


def Kahoot_Spammer(Game_Pin, NickNAME):
    chromedriver = os.chdir(r'C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver_win32.exe')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    browser.get('https://kahoot.it/')

    game_pin = browser.find_element_by_id("Game PIN")
    Name = browser.find_element_by_id("Nickname")

    game_pin.send_keys(Game_Pin)
    Enter_Press()
    Name.send_keys(NickNAME)
    Enter_Press()




Kahoot_Spammer(Game_Pin, NickNAME)
```

I am brand new to Python programming and programming in general. Anyway I have been looking for a clear answer as to why this isn't working for quite a while now. I pretty sure I have the file in the PATH but it still cant find it for some reason. Here is the error I keep getting. Any thoughts

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ovvip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\KahootSpammer.py", line 28, in <module>
    Kahoot_Spammer(Game_Pin, NickNAME)
  File "C:\Users\ovvip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\KahootSpammer.py", line 13, in Kahoot_Spammer
    chromedriver = os.chdir(r'C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver_win32.exe')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\WebDriver\\bin\\chromedriver_win32.exe'
```

Comment: try this line of code driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")

Answer (score 0):

`os.chdir` [changes the current directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) to the specified one. You don't need to go to the directory, you just need to tell selenium where it is.

Removing those two lines of code and adding this should work:

`webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver_win32.exe')`

Comment: I am getting a different error now: 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_win32' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home'

Comment: I think there are permissions issues try in cmd icacls "pathtochromedriver" /grant Users:F

Comment: I put the command in the command prompt but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Have you given the full path of chrome driver here including .Exe?